# Submitting method into ExecutorService Java

Tags: java, methods, executorservice

So I have this code here, that adds my "NamePrinter" runnable class as ExecutorService tasks. Everything works fine, but I'd like to get rid of that extra class. So I am asking is there a way to submit method to ExexutorService?

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
public void start(){
        Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<>();
        final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        futures.add(es.submit(new NamePrinter(name)));
        }

        es.shutdown();
}
```

But I'd like it to be something like this:

```
public void start(){
            Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<>();
            final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            futures.add(es.submit(namePrint(i+"name"))); // This code doesn't work, I just made it so you could understand what I mean.
            }

            es.shutdown();
    }

public void namePrint(String name){  // I'd like this to be the task that ExecutorService runs.

System.out.println(name);

}
```

Is this something that is possible to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest you can come as an anonymous inner class:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final int x = i;
    futures.add(es.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            namePrint(x + "name");
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: This is another Runnable class. It is like a syntactic sugar over your original code.

Comment: Can I acces my public class variables from this anonymous inner class?

Comment: @RohitMalish: Did you try it? :) (Yes, you can. You can even access private ones and final local variables. Search for "anonymous inner class" for more information.)

Comment: @RohitMalish: You should edit a short but *complete* example into your question then. It should be fine.

Comment: In java 8:   es.submit( () -> { namePrint(x+name); } );

Comment: One extra question how can I make this run without pausing whole program?

Answer (score 3):

You are essentially asking: *is Java supporting functions as first class citizens* (sometimes it is refered as *closures* or *lambdas*) - no, **you can't do this in Java**. You can in Groovy, Scala, JavaScript, C#... but not in Java.

Your `NamePrinter` class (probably implementing `Runnable` or `Callable`) is the closest you can get in Java and this is the Java way (or you can use anonymous inner class).

Comment: That is, you can't do this in Java *until* Java 8 adds support for closures.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer: well, assumming we'll live long enough ;-)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz are you alive?

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, I think you'll not be able to do *exactly* what you want, because the `run` method of `Runnable` interface doesn't take any arguments. However, you can use **lambda expressions** since **Java 8**. So you have few options now:

1 - Define the method on-the-fly

```
final String name = "whatever";

exServ.execute(() -> {            
    System.out.println(name);
});
```

2 - Define a static method and then use static method reference

```
public static void printName()
{
    System.out.println(ClassNameX.name);
}

exServ.execute(ClassTest::printName);
```

3 - Create an instance of your NamePrinter class - which doesn't need to implement the `Runnable` interface - to store the parameters and then use instance method reference.

```
NamePrinter np = new NamePrinter("testName");

exServ.execute(np::namePrint);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some options for this:

1. Using anonymous class

   ```
   es.submit { new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     //do your stuff here
    }
   });
   ```
2. Use languages which support closures like [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/). However the API must support this, which ExecutorService doesn't.
3. Wait for [Java 8](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/jdk-8-closure-syntax-decision/231601075) which will introduce closures.